# client and server + sorting

Tags: c

In my program, I'm getting username as startup parameter and getting the user-id from server. 
Sever and client are connected! 
But I need to put the username and the user-id(that belongs to the username) together, send them back to the server and to the end sort them with respect to user-ids. Any suggestions?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Use [`qsort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) to sort. If you post the code that you have, people will be more able (and more willing) to assist.

Comment: The question is that how can I put the username and the user-id(that belongs to the username) together? Afterwards sort them >With respect to user-ids< .

Answer (score 0):

Just send them both to the server, taking care to include some kind of delimiter so it's possible to parse the stream and identify which part is which.

For instance, you could separate the two with a NIL-byte, with a final NIL after the userid, too. This assumes that both are strings.

On the server, just store the incoming data into an array of structs, and sort the array with `qsort()` when you have all the data collected.